# How close can you put casement windows together?

Tags: framing, windows, sunroom

New to framing windows, I have a 50 inch wide opening and I want to put 2 casement windows in next to each other without mulling together. I was wondering with just 1 king stud in between what you do with the window flanges (overlap them when nailing)?

Worried about exterior finish when I frame them next to each other and having enough space in between for whatever trim I need. I literally know nothing about doing windows as this is my first time framing them in.

I can't seem to find any internet info about putting 2 windows next to each other other than mulled windows.

Comment: I suspect the answer is: it depends how far open the windows swing.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the question about how to frame two windows closely but I'm curious why you don't want to just buy a double (pre mulled) window or a "French" one that looks mulled but creates an unobstructed opening.   You can buy flangeless windows to avoid the overlap question.  If they do overlap, make sure before buying that it's just the flanges and some of the frame doesn't overhang too.  You could shim the other three sides of the higher window so its face is parallel with the wall.

Comment: I agree with @jay613 and recommend you buy a twin vs two singles.

Comment: There's a **clue** here: "*I can't seem to find any internet info about putting 2 windows next to each other other than mulled windows.*" you can't find it, because that's not the way it's done. When you "literally know nothing about" a process it's not a terrible idea to try it the way other folks have successfully done it before inventing your own way and discovering why nobody else does it that way for yourself. But learn however you like, if you're determined to...